# Navbar collapse menu not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've seen this question asked a lot on here, but my code seems to be correct.  My data-target id matches the id of the collapse div.  not sure why then menu isn't opening when I click on the hamburger icon.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">LoopLab</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#explore-head-section" class="nav-link">Explore</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#create-head-section" class="nav-link">Create</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#share-head-section" class="nav-link">Share</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems working when I use your code with Bootstrap 4 template. make sure you properly load the JS and CSS for Bootstrap. use the small window to see the hamburger menu icon.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">LoopLab</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#explore-head-section" class="nav-link">Explore</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#create-head-section" class="nav-link">Create</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#share-head-section" class="nav-link">Share</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>



  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For project Angular:

make sure you have the `bootstrap.css`, `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` files in the `angular.json` file.

example :

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
```

Comment: add : "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"